# How do I compare actual vs. expectedd SHA256TreeHash in Amazon Glacier?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am getting archive information back from Glacier that contains the archive's SHA256TreeHash.  When I retrieve and download the archive, I use the SHA256TreeHash routine on Amazon's site ( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/checksum-calculations.html#checksum-calculations-examples ).  The hash from the archive information is a string.  The hash from the routine is a byte array (containing some unprintable characters).  I tried to base64 the hash, but the results of the two are vastly different.

Returned from the archive retrieval job:
a89877bebd71dcb73437d0faf099d1139a37dee09fd7a241302ff15dfaa62170

Returned from using the Amazon provided routine for hashing the downloaded file:
qJh3vr1x3Lc0N9D68JnRE5o33uCf16JBMC/xXfqmIXA=

How do I get the treehash from the byte array into a string hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a89877be...` is the hex representation of the bytes `0xa8` `0x98` `0x77` `0xbe` `...`.

Convert from hex back to bytes, or base64 decode and convert the bytes to hex characters and you should get something you can compare.  Indeed, the actual bytes (after being converted from hex), above, do convert to a base64 representation beginning with `qJh3...`.